# Change UILabel from appDelegate

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I want to do some stuff from the appDelegate in Xcode. One of these things are to change a UILabel.

```
ViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil]        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id"];


viewController.label.text = @"heeej";
```

I was told this would do the trick. Doesn't work. Label doesn't change. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

1. Don't do anything in the AppDelegate except for loading the window an the initial view controllers (if needed).
2. You are instantiating a new view controller in the first line. I assume you already have a view controller and you want to change the label in that view controller. Than you need a reference to that view controller and use this reference to send messages to it.
3. The label should not be a property of the view controller. You should try to follow the design pattern Model-View-Controller or the pattern Model-View-ViewModel. Ask you preferred search engine what those are if you don't know.
4. `id` as an identifier for anything in Objective-C is a bad idea because this is used as an object type.

**Edit:** You don't need a reference to change a property in the view controller. Use notifications to update the label. The system sends a notification with the name `UIApplicationWillEnterForgroundNotification' (see [here][1]). Add the view controller as an observer to the`[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` for this name and react on the notification. Read the Apple documentation if you don't know what I am talking about.

Comment: Okay thanks great! You are correct. xCode has already created a ViewController for, i need to connect to that instance (or object) in the appDelegate. Because in appDelegate I have methods like: - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application. The change of label is just an example. All I want to do is to give some of my properties values.

Basically: how do i find the reference, in appDelegate, to an already created ViewController, created by xCode in the Storyboard.